How to extend interface with overloaded method in TypeScript?
This works
interface Functions {
  size<T>(a: T[]): number
  size<T>(o: Record<string, T>): number
}

But this doesn't, run it. How to make it work? The overloaded method is not known at the time the interface Functions declared and should be added later, incrementally.
interface Functions {}

interface ArrayFunctions {
  size<T>(a: T[]): number
}

interface ObjectFunctions {
  size<T>(o: Record<string, T>): number
}

interface Functions extends ArrayFunctions, ObjectFunctions {}

Error:
Interface 'Functions' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ArrayFunctions' and 'ObjectFunctions'.
Named property 'size' of types 'ArrayFunctions' and 'ObjectFunctions' are not identical.ts(2320)


Interface extension isn't checked loosely the way merging is... if you need this behavior I'd say you should use an intersection, possibly like this playground link shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?
